# Unable to unlock drive with BitLocker To Go

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I have an SDCard connected to my laptop through the internal reader

I have encrypted it with BitLocker To Go

Everytime I start my PC or Re-plug the drive I have a prompt to unlock the drive and then I can use it like any other drive

However, today I unplugged the card, and after a while I remembered something so I re-plugged it

I have been presented with BitLocker To Go Reader, I can extract some files with it
of BitLocker 
But I want full access to the drive? Just like it did before.

And in the control panel of BitLocker, It says the drive is not encrypted, which confuses me.

I am very sure that the drive is encrypted

Please help very urgent, need help in hours if possible

Comment: Sounds like not safetly ejecting the disk you have caused yourself a problem.  You have basically corrupted the drive.  You should restore your file from a backup and always eject the disk before simply removing it.